# Python Pandas: interpolate datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation

Lets say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7},
 'date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2019-05-23 15:39:45'),
  1: np.nan,
  2: pd.Timestamp('2019-05-23 15:40:49')}})
```

How do I simply impute the missing value as the time in between the two values? In this example, that value would be: `(df.date[2]-df.date[0])/2 + df.date[0]` = `Timestamp('2019-05-23 15:40:17')`

Can I do this without using loops looking for missing values?

I tried converting the datetime column into a timestamp, interpolating, and then converting back. Unfortunelyall the dates converted incorrectly and I ended up with dates in the 1970s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can cast the datetime column to its floating point representation (nanoseconds since 1970-01-01), interpolate these, and cast back to datetime, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7},
                   'date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2019-05-23 15:39:45'),
                            1: pd.Timestamp('NaT'),
                            2: pd.Timestamp('2019-05-23 15:40:49')}})

s = pd.Series(df['date'].values.astype(float))
s[s<0] = np.NaN

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(s.interpolate())
```

```
df
   values                date
0       5 2019-05-23 15:39:45
1       6 2019-05-23 15:40:17
2       7 2019-05-23 15:40:49
```